# Using HTML file to Query a Google Spreadsheet using a Textbox for Query, using App Script

Tags: javascript, html, database, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet which I have more than 1000 lines, each column is a field, one of the columns has the field called Domain, "which will be the value I need to query", my application using HTML will need to query using a Text box the HTML to a function, to search the Spreadsheet and return the values of the same line in the HTML.

Now here is the HTML Code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.10.0/angular-material.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.0/material.blue-green.min.css" /> 
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.10.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.0/material.min.js"></script>

    <?!= include('WebPage.js'); ?>
    <?!= include('Style'); ?>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="webApp">
    <div ng-controller="webAppCtrl">
      <div>
        <md-toolbar class="md-theme-light">
          <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
            <div>DeLight App</div>
          </div>
        </md-toolbar>
    <div id="body">
    <div layout="row" layout-align="center start" layout-margin layout-fill layout-padding>
      <div>
        <form action="#">
          <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
            <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample3" />
            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample3">Enter Domain</label>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
   <div layout="row" layout-align="center start" layout-margin layout-fill layout-padding>
     <div id="leftContainer" class="md-whiteframe-z2" flex="50">
       <md-toolbar class="md-theme-light">
         <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
           <div>Customer Info</div>
         </div>
       </md-toolbar>
       Pull Customer Info here from Sheet
     </div>
     <div id= "rightContainer" class="md-whiteframe-z2" flex="50">
       <md-toolbar class="md-theme-light">
         <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
           <div>Task List</div>
         </div>
       </md-toolbar>
       <md-list-item>
         <p>Verified Domain Owner</p>
         <md-checkbox class="md-secondary"></md-checkbox>
       </md-list-item>
       <md-list-item>
         <p>User Creation</p>
         <md-checkbox class="md-secondary"></md-checkbox>
       </md-list-item>
       <md-list-item>
         <p>Dual Delivery</p>
         <md-checkbox class="md-secondary"></md-checkbox>
       </md-list-item>
     </div>
   </div>
     </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the Web App Function Scripts page:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate()
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setTitle('Test')
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .getContent();
}

function testSheet(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("abc123456");
  Logger.log(ss.getName());
}
```

The problem that I have is that I don't know how I can store the information that the user submits to the Textbox so I can later search my spreadsheet using a snippet I found here which is:

```
function test(){
 var sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById("abc123456");
 var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues(); // read all data in the sheet
 for(n=0;n<data.length;++n){ // iterate row by row and examine data in column A
 if(data[n][0].toString().match('searchvariable')=='searchvariable'){ data[n][5] = 'YES'};// if column A contains 'xyz' then set value in index [5] (is column F)
 }
 Logger.log(data)
 sh.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data); // write back to the sheet
 }
```

Any Ideas how can I achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the data out of the form, then send the form values to a server side `.gs` script function using `google.script.run.myFunctionName()`.

[google.script.run - Client Side API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

There are various ways that you can get the values out of the input fields.  You can get the form as a whole, and send a modified form object to the server, or you can get the values individually.

If you get the form object, google changes the form object.  The ***only*** way that a `.gs` function can get values out of the form object is by using the HTML `name` attribute.  In other words, the only way you can get the form object strategy to work, is by giving every input field a name attribute with a name.

```
<input name='myNameGoesHere' class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample3" />
```

The Google documentation shows putting the `google.script.run` code directly into the `click` attribute of the input button.  You can try it that way, or put the code into a separate script tag.

```
<input type="button" value="Not Clicked"
    onclick="google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(updateButton)
        .withUserObject(this)
        .getEmail()" />
```

### HTML code:

```
<script>
  //Put an anonymous function into the browsers window object
  window.callServer = function(theFormObject) {
    google.script.run
     .search(theFormObject);
</script> 

<form>
  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
    <input name='domain' class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample3" />
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample3">Enter Domain</label>
    <input type="button" value="Not Clicked" onclick="callServer(this.parent.parent)"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

### Code.gs

```
function search(myForm) {
  //Look in VIEW menu, and LOGS menu Item to see if the form was passed in
  Logger.log('myForm: ' + myForm);
  var domain = myForm.domain;
  Logger.log('domain: ' + domain);
}
```

Comment: Hi Sorry to re ask but I think I mess up in something in here:

'<script>google.script.run.search();</script>

<form>
          <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
            <input name='domain' class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample3" />
            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample3">Enter Domain</label>
            <input type="button" value="Not Clicked"
    onclick="google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(updateButton)
        .withUserObject(this)
        .getEmail()" />
          </div>
        </form>'

Comment: I don't know if that was correctly set up and on the gs I added a function called search():

function search() {
  var domain = index.html.form.domain;
}

Comment: Hi Sorry to continue asking things, In the `.gs` I put the code you sent me 

`function search(myForm) {
  //Look in VIEW menu, and LOGS menu Item to see if the form was passed in
  Logger.log('myForm: ' + myForm);
  var domain = myForm.domain;
  Logger.log('domain: ' + domain);
} function search(myForm) {
  //Look in VIEW menu, and LOGS menu Item to see if the form was passed in
  Logger.log('myForm: ' + myForm);
  var domain = myForm.domain;
  Logger.log('domain: ' + domain);
}`

Comment: And I got an error saying: TypeError: Cannot read property "domain" from undefined. (line 21, file "Code")

And I also put the code in HTML side: 

`<script>
  //Put an anonymous function into the browsers window object
  window.callServer = function(myform) {
    google.script.run.search(myform);
</script>`

and modified the form to be name myform:

Comment: `<form name="myform">
  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
    <input name='domain' class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample3" />
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample3">Enter Domain</label>
    <input type="button" value="Not Clicked" onclick="callServer(this.parent.parent)"/>
  </div>
</form>`

Any Ideas, I'm really sorry to keep asking

Comment: Maybe it has to do with `this.parent.parent`.  I'm not sure it that's correct.  Do some research on the key work `this`.  [Stackoverflow this keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)